# How to show data from a database with a requirement?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show some data from a table in my database but i want it to show a specific ID "rid" that i get from another page with the code:

my SQL code is:

```
SELECT rid
     , tid
     , qid
     , aid
     , points 
  FROM result 
  WHEN rid = $val
```

if i delete `WHEN rid=$val` i will get all the all the "points" from my database. But i want to show a specific ID (rid). what should i do?

Comment: What isn't working with this code? From what I can tell the only issue is that WHEN should be WHERE (a simple typo).

Answer (score 2):

The correct SQL Statement would be

```
SELECT rid, tid, qid, aid, points FROM result WHERE rid=$val
```